# JQuery: I want to refresh when countdown reaches zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to refresh when countdown reaches zero.
**window.location.reload();**
So I added a refresh to countdown <= 0.
However, the refresh is infinite.
How can I do a single refresh after the countdown reaches zero?

The refresh script is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  endTimeCheck();
  window.setInterval(function() {
    endTimeCheck();
  }, 1000);
});

var timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
function endTimeCheck() {
  $("span[name='betStatus']").each(function() {
    var $span = $(this);
    var play_timestamp = parseInt($(this).attr("timestamp"));
    var countdown = play_timestamp - timestamp - 32700;
    if (countdown <= 0) {
      if (!$span.hasClass('closed')) {
        $span.css("color", "#FF5733").css("font-weight", "bold").text("finish");
        var tdObj = $span.parents('.event-list-item').addClass("disable");
        window.location.reload();
      }
    }
    // 30분
    else if (countdown < 1800) {
      var minute = Math.floor(countdown / 60);
      var second = countdown % 60;
      if (second < 10) {
        second = "0" + second;
      }
      $(this).css("color", "DarkOrange").css("font-weight", "bold").text(minute + ":" + second);
    }
    // 1시간
    else if (countdown <= 3600) {
      var minute = Math.floor(countdown / 60);
      var second = countdown % 60;
      if (second < 10) {
        second = "0" + second;
      }
      $(this).css("font-weight", "bold").text(minute + ":" + second);
    }
  });
  timestamp++;
}
```

Comment: The webpage is stateless, so, every time it gets loaded the script will be run. You are going to have to change your approach. Perhaps use a query parameter like ?pagerefreshed=true. So you would use window.location instead and check if the url does contain the query string before you change the window.location.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve this is using [cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

When your countdown reach 0, you set a cookie (ie: refreshed, true).
Don't forget to check if the cookie **doesn't exists** before your countdown function.

```
document.cookie = 'refreshed=true';
```

You can also set an expiration time if you want your function to be re-enabled every 2hs.

```
var now=new Date();
var expireTime=new Date();
expireTime.setHours(now.getHours()+2);
document.cookie = 'refreshed=true; expires='+expireTime.toGMTString();
```